# Can anyone identify this kind of timestamp? 329813840

Tags: database, encoding, timestamp, backend

I am trying to build an application, to collect data from my Photovoltaic system. I have found an URL to request data and managed to get a kind of CSV file back.

Ever row in this CSV File starts with a timestamp like this one `329813840`. This one should be our current date.

I already check if it is an unix-timestamp but as a unix-timestamp it would be the 14. June 1980.

Does anyone know what kind of timestamp this is?

Comment: Do you have an idea on which date it should represent? There are many "epochs", so with different starting years (e.g. DOS and GPS). Ideally you should know two dates with relative timestamp, so you can check if the scale it is 1 second (it could be also 1/100, or also 2 or 4 seconds), and get also the origin point (the date of timestamp = 0).

Comment: It shoud be the 27.11.2022. If it is counted in seconds the timestamp 0 is about 10,4 years in the past. I have looked online for common epochs but i could not find any that started about 10 years ago. All I could find started before 2000.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. Here the answer if anyone has the same Problem.
It is seconds since the Installation of the Photovoltaic system. It is independent from any Epoch.